# Error name lookup of "i" changed for iso 'for' scoping

Tags: c++

```
stack<string> myStack;       
string TemStore;      
string return_value;      
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)      
    if((input.at(i)!='32') && (input.at(i)!= '46'))     
        TemStore+=input.at(i);
    if(input.at(i)=='32')    //problem occured here <<  dont know why it says as the title.    

        myStack.push(TemStore);     
        myStack.push('32');    
        TemStore='\0';     
    }
```

i dont know why i getting error like this.. can anyone help me?

Comment: surround the body of `for` with `{}`

Comment: You also have a closing brace without any matching opening brace. Copy-paste error?

Comment: C++ is not python, you can't create blocks just with indentation.

Comment: Do not edit your question if you have a new question; create a new question.

Comment: If you want to ask a new/different question, ask a new/different question. Don't edit this one to something completely different--that leads to a confusing mess, with answers that are no longer related to the question at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use braces with your for-loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++) {  // brace
    if((input.at(i)!='32') && (input.at(i)!= '46'))     
        TemStore+=input.at(i);
    if(input.at(i)=='32')    

        myStack.push(TemStore);     
        myStack.push('32');    
        TemStore='\0';     
}  // brace
```

Otherwise, the loop will only apply to this part:

```
if((input.at(i)!='32') && (input.at(i)!= '46'))     
    TemStore+=input.at(i);
```

And the `i` used here:

```
if(input.at(i)=='32')    //problem occured here <<  dont know why it says as the title.
```

will be out of scope.

---

In addition, it looks like your second if-statement needs braces as well:

```
if(input.at(i)=='32') { // brace
    myStack.push(TemStore);     
    myStack.push('32');    
    TemStore='\0';
} // brace
```

Basically, you need to use braces whenever you want a for-loop, if-statement, etc. to apply to two or more statements.  Only when you have one statement can you omit them:

```
// Needs braces because there is more than one statement underneath.
if (condition) {
    // statement 1
    // statement 2
}

// Does not need braces because there is only one statement underneath.
if (condition)
    // statement 1
```